# Best .Net Blog Engine for a Web Form under a Master Page

Tags: asp.net, webforms, master-pages, blogs

I have a pretty slick website and I wanted to add a simple blog system to it, without too much work. I've looked into a few blog systems, but none of them seem to be simple almost control like systems.

So anyone have any recommendations for a simple asp.net blog engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's usually not much to a blog.  A table to hold the entries, a page to make entries, and a page that lists them out.

If you want people to leave comments, then again it's not that hard.  A table to hold the comments and a section on your blog viewing page to add a comment.  I would use some form of a captcha entry, their name, and the actual comment itself; no need to "register" to be a user.

All in all, probably a good couple hours work; which would be less than implementing someone elses stuff.  Just be sure to sanitize the comments to prevent xss attacks.

Comment: point taken about the simplicity of the code you propose, but IMO the OP has asked for an implementation out in the wild as compared to building an own implementation...

Comment: Sunny, you are right, however, Christ does bring up a valid point. Might just be easier and better for the future to program my own. Thank you both for your input.

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.Net site contains a section for community open source projects and starter kits. One of the open source sections is blogs:

http://www.asp.net/community/projects

Subtext is simple to setup, but if you want to integrate blogging into your site you can try BlogEngine. You can find links to both of them in the link above.